# Best tactic for creating complicated 3D patterns?

Tags: modeling

I really want to be able to create a fancy piece of furniture like the armchair below, but the gold parts are what elude me. I've never really been able to come up with a great way to model complex patterns like that in 3D whilst keeping it fitting to the shape of the chair and still have good geometry. It's ok if the pattern is just on a flat surface like a wall because then I can just make an image and plug it into a bump node for the wall's material, but I have no idea how to create clean 3D shapes like that with loads of detail. If anybody has any tips as to what method I should use/how to go around creating something, please let me know. Thank you! :)

[image]

Comment: maybe use bezier curves? watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJsxKWxAhMk

Comment: Sculpt, retopo. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @moonboots Thank you for the suggestion! I'm watching part 1 and part 2 right now and it's a pretty awesome method. I actually tried using bezier before but never knew about that custom profile thing for some reason so that was an amazing find! :)

Comment: @brockmann I haven't tried sculpting yet since I'm unfortunately not the best at it, but I have tried bezier and shaping using a sub-divided cube. :)